# hcitool scan doesnot scan devices. hcitool scan: Operation not supported

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, scanning, imx6, hci

I am using hcitool to scan bluetooth device(Windows PC) from iMx6 device. I had run below commands, and it results "Operation not supported". How I can solve this?

```
~# hcitool scan
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Operation not supported
```

Regards,

Aysha